# Counting idempotent $2×2$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

Question: if $A$ is a real $2×2$ matrix such that $A^2 - A= 0$ then which of the following are true?

(a) there are infinitely many such matrices $A$

(b) there are finitely many such matrices $A$

(C) $A$ has to be diagonal matrix.

Please help me. I know that, the minimal polynomial must divides the annihilating polynomial of matrix. 
Hence possibilities of minimal polynomial are:
$m(x) =x$ or $m(x) = x-1$ or $m(x) =x(x-1)$ but how to determine number of matrices from this?

Comment: Can you write down any solutions for $A$?

Comment: Yes sure$ A= 0$ where $0$ is $2×2$ zero matrix and $A = I$ where I is 2×2 identity mstrix

Comment: These are two solutions, but are the two least interesting solutions. Any more?

Comment: I mean identity matrix of 2×2 order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the matrices $MDM^{-1}$ where $M$ is any $2\times 2$ invertible matrix and
$$D=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
P.S. Explicit example: for $\theta\in [0,\pi),$
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\sin^2(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)&\cos^2(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Nice. But How you done it?

Comment: Oh using JC form? any matrix which is similar to above matrix is also idempotent? Is am I right?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi $D^2-D=0$. Then if $A=MDM^{-1}$ is similar do $D$ and $A^2-A=M(D^2-D)M^{-1}$.

Comment: Is $(MDM^{-1})^2 = M A^2 M^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Got it thank u so much sir. For helping me

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes, well done.

Answer (score 3):

The matrix of the orthogonal projection onto a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is idempotent. Since there are infinitely many such subspaces, there are infinitely many idempotent matrices.

Actually, this argument proves that there are infinitely many similarity classes of idempotent matrices.

Comment: In fact, $A^2=A$ is a common definition of a projection, orthogonal or otherwise.